# Sql Join Query using MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hello I Have a problem in getting rows from one table after comparing both. Detail of Both Table are as follows:-

I am using Ms Access database.

```
TableA is having a data of numeric type (Field Name is A it is primary key)
----------
 Field A
==========
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5

Table B is having data of numeric type ( Field Name is A it is foreign key)
--------
Field A
========
  2
  4
```

Now I am using below query which is this

```
select a.a 
    from a a
        , b b 
    where a.a <> b.b
```

I want to show all the data from Table A which is not equal to Table B. But the above query is not working as I described.

Can you help me in this regard.

Regards,

Fawad Munir

Comment: "query is not working as I described" - care to describe what's not working exactly?

Comment: What do you mean by "all the data from table A which is not equal to table B"? For each row in table A, your query will match every row for table B where column a is different than column b, is that really what you want?

Answer (score 1):

In an attempt at clarity, I've used upper case for tables and lower case for fields:

```
Select A.a
FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON A.a=B.b
WHERE B.b is null
```

This will show all the records in A that are not in B (I assume that's what you want).

Read up on Access outer joins. In the query designer you double click the join and select something like "all records from table a and only the matching records in table b".

Answer (score 0):

In your question you said that the name of the field in table B is 'A'.  Given that, I'd say that your query should be something like

```
select a.a
  from a, b
  where a.a <> b.a
```

But I'm not sure this will do what you want.  I *think* you're trying to find rows in table A which do not have a matching row in table B, in which case you might try

```
SELECT A.A
  FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
  ON (B.A = A.A)
WHERE B.A IS NULL
```

Try that and see if it does what you want.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly if Access would accept the syntax, but here how I would do in SQL Server.

```
select a.a
    from TableA a
    where a.a NOT IN (
        select b.a
            from TableB b                
    )
```

or even as above-mentioned:

```
select a.a
    from TableA a
        left outer join TableB b on b.a = a.a
    where b.a IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not entirely clear what you are trying to achieve, but its sounds like you are attempting to solve the common problem of finding rows in Table A missing associated data in Table B.   If this is the case, it appears you misunderstand the semantics of the join you tried.  In which case, you have 2 problems, because the understanding the the JOIN operation is critical to working with relational databases.

In relation to the first problem, please research how to express a subquery using the IN operator.   Something like

```
...  WHERE a NOT IN (SELECT a from b)
```

In relation to the second problem, try your query without the WHERE restriction, and see what is returned.   Once you understand what the join is doing, you will see why applying a WHERE restriction to it will not solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to see every row in A for which column a contains a value that cannot be found in any column b value of B.  You can get this data in several ways.

I think using NOT IN is the clearest, personally:

```
 SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE columnA NOT IN 
   (SELECT columnB FROM tableB WHERE columnB IS NOT NULL)
```

Many people prefer a filtered JOIN:

```
 SELECT tableA.* FROM tableA LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB
    ON tableA.columnA = tableB.columnB WHERE tableB.columnB IS NULL
```

There is a NOT EXISTS variant as well:

```
 SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE columnA NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE columnB = tableA.columnA)
```